# Laravel-why admin receives every email message?

Tags: email, laravel-8, laravel-admin

I am working on a web application with multiple users, and I have some issue with sending emails.
Sending is working fine, no problems, but the issue is that every mail interaction between visitors and users is sent to admin email address stated in env file. I am using gmail for sending, Laravel 8.
For example, visitor A has sent a message to user B. User B received mail correctly, but also admin received message.
Thanks for help.

Here is my EmailsController

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;

class EmailsController extends Controller
{   
public function send(Request $request)
    {
        function sentence_case($string) {
            $sentences = explode(" ",$string);
            $sentences = array_reverse($sentences);
            $new_string = '';
            foreach ($sentences as $key => $sentence) {
                $new_string = ucfirst(mb_strtolower(trim($sentence)))." ".$new_string;
            }
            return $new_string;
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'ime' => 'required',   //visitor name
            'email' => 'required', // visitor email address
            'poruka' => 'required'  //visitor message
        ]);

        $ime = $request->get('ime');
        $ime = sentence_case($ime);
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $poruka = $request->get('poruka');
        
       Mail::send('emails.message', [
        'name' => $ime,
        'email' => $email,
        'comment' => $poruka ],
        function ($m) use ($email) {
                $m->from($email);
                $m->to('usersemail@yahoo.com', 'MyApp')
                        ->subject('Website Contact Form');
});
/* usersemail@yahoo.com is registered user email address different from aplication admin/owner email addres stated in env file, but admin receives this message */


        if (Mail::failures()) {
            return response()->Fail('Sorry! Please try again latter');
        }else{
             return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting me, I will get back to you soon!');
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you put the mail sender function?

Comment: I updated my post with code so please see.

Comment: When you delete the admin value from Env this works fine?

Comment: I found mistake this morning. It was because admin email is gmail.com mail, and other admin's email address for testing are gmail import accounts (user@app.hr admin@app.eu and similar are received through gmail). So, it seemed as double messaging but actually it wasn't. Gmail have received all messages, with no delay. It was mistake in my observation. Application works fine. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Grate news, have nice day